# comparing and appending python lists of different lengths

Tags: python, list, append, comparison

I have two time lists (`time` which has 140 elements of different time stamps and `sessionStart` which has 13 elements documenting the start of a trial). I need to compare these two lists to find when each element is in `time` is bigger than the first element in `sessionStart` but smaller than the second element in `sessionStart`. The code is supposed to append the first element of `sessionStart` if it matches to an empty list `start`. When run, `start` remains empty

```
x = 0
while x < len(time):
    i = 0
    while i < len(sessionStart)-1 and x < len(time):
        if time[x] >= sessionStart[i] and time[x] < sessionStart[i+1]:
            start.append(sessionStart[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            x += 1
```

Comment: where are you declaring the start list?

Answer (score 0):

the `start` list must be declared before you can use it, and should be *outside* any loops you're using, or it will be overwritten.

You can also iterate through these lists much more simply with a couple python functions:

```
    start = []

    for element in time:
        for i in range(len(sessionStart)-1):
            if element >= sessionStart[i] and element < sessionStart[i+1]:
                start.append(sessionStart[i])
```

- `for x in my_list` will iterate through every element (which  can be
  used with the variable `x`) in a list named `my_list`.
- `for in range(value)` iterates from 0 to the length of (value-1), so
  no need to use index variables and add 1 to them each time

Additionally, if you're trying to compare timestamps, you should be converting them to datetime objects using the [datetime library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

For example, if your timestamp was '2018-08-15', you can turn it into a date to do comparisons by doing `datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')`

So used in the loop, would look like:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    start = []

    for timestamp in time:
        timestamp = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d')
        for i in range(len(sessionStart)-1):
            if timestamp >= datetime.strptime(sessionStart[i], '%Y-%m-%d')
                and timestamp < datetime.strptime(sessionStart[i+1], '%Y-%m-%d'):
            start.append(sessionStart[i])
```

Of course, thats assuming your timestamps are in YYYY-MM-DD format which I'm sure they aren't, you'll have to update the format string according to your timestamps format, you can also get seconds, milliseconds, minutes, etc., at the above link

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The timestamps are YYYY-MM-DD, HH:MM:SS format. I looked at the above link but I'm not really sure how to format this in my code

Comment: I also tried your method which seems to work but the length of the start list is only 125 when it should be the same length as the time list which is 140